# Hibernate statistics in spring boot not working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, statistics, spring-boot

I have a small sample app here

```
https://github.com/jimbasilio/SpringBoot
```

that creates some simple data in the database and some other things I'm working on to kick the tires on spring boot (side note: so far i LOVE spring boot!!).  If you clone the git repo you can visit the url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/hello/get/1
```

and it'll load from the database and write the hibernate statistics to the console.

I do have a problem though, with or without configuring hibernate statistics via the application.properties file:

```
hibernate.generate_statistics=true
```

when i write the hibernate statistics out i get nothing useful.  I'm fetching the statistics via:

```
Session session = (Session) this.entityManager.getDelegate();
session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().logSummary();
HelloEntity entity = helloRepository.findOne(id);
entityManager.flush();
session.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().logSummary();
```

my SECOND log message (after flush) is below.  You can see it doesn't even register sessions being opened.  I'm using spring boot 1.0.1.RELEASE.

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

log file:

```
2014-04-28 20:51:29.415  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000161: Logging statistics....
2014-04-28 20:51:29.416  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000251: Start time: 1398732682476
2014-04-28 20:51:29.416  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000242: Sessions opened: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.416  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000241: Sessions closed: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.416  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000266: Transactions: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.416  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000258: Successful transactions: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000187: Optimistic lock failures: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000105: Flushes: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000048: Connections obtained: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000253: Statements prepared: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000252: Statements closed: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.417  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000239: Second level cache puts: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000237: Second level cache hits: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000238: Second level cache misses: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000079: Entities loaded: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000080: Entities updated: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000078: Entities inserted: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.418  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000076: Entities deleted: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.419  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000077: Entities fetched (minimize this): 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.419  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000033: Collections loaded: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.419  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000036: Collections updated: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.419  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000035: Collections removed: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.419  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000034: Collections recreated: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000032: Collections fetched (minimize this): 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000438: NaturalId cache puts: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000439: NaturalId cache hits: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000440: NaturalId cache misses: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000441: Max NaturalId query time: 0ms
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000442: NaturalId queries executed to database: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000210: Queries executed to database: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.420  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000215: Query cache puts: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000433: update timestamps cache puts: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000434: update timestamps cache hits: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000435: update timestamps cache misses: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000213: Query cache hits: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000214: Query cache misses: 0
2014-04-28 20:51:29.421  INFO 18044 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.s.internal.ConcurrentStatisticsImpl  : HHH000173: Max query time: 0ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Hibernate is just not reading your config.

According to [Hibernate's Reference Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-configuration) you're supposed to put Hibernate configuration on hibernate.properties or hibernate.cfg.xml. If those didn't work you might also want to try the programmatic config.

Comment: that was it!!  i'm sort of shocked.  i thought all the properties were merged together.  thank you for your answer!

Comment: turns out you can prefix settings for the native JPA provider and keep them in the application.properties, i missed this in the spring boot docs.  so in my case I added: spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true to my application.properties file and things also worked.  I prefer this to a hibernate.properties file since I can override with application-{profile}.properties for dev/test/prod settings.  thanks again for the kick, it helped.

Answer (score 95):

Use  `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`
instead-of
`hibernate.generate_statistics=true`

Comment: this is the right way I mean "spring boot"ish way to do it.

Comment: Additionally make sure logging is enabled for hibernate. E.g: `logging.level.org.hibernate=INFO`

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issue in my spring boot application. All the tutorials and threads I found told me to use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true`
but it was **not** working.
Then I added hibernate.properties file to the resource folder and inside the file add
`hibernate.generate_statistics=true`
Then I restart my spring boot app and it works like a charm.

So I guess there is some bug/issue in some specific spring boot version(I was using 2.2.13) where the `generate_statistics` would not be taken by hibernate from `spring.jpa.properties`. Btw, all the other properties like `format_sql` is working by setting up in spring.jpa.properties